# Adding numbers from one series to a series of letters within the same dataframes, possibly using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

I have a subset of a much larger dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['car- at', 'car- ar', 'truck- br', 'car- at'],
        'SysNum': [1, 2, 3, 4 ],
            }
     Name     SysNum
0   car- at     1   
1   car- ar     2   
2   truck- br   3   
3   car- at     4
```

I need to be able to enter the numbers into the name after the - .  The dash is in each name so I tried to use a couple Regex lines but I am unable to get it so far.  The dataframe should look like:

```
    Name      SysNum    Count
0   car- at     1      car-1 at
1   car- ar     2      car-2 ar
2   truck- br   3      truck-3 br
3   car- at     4      car-4 at
```

I have used something similar before:

```
df['BaseName'] = [re.sub('(?<=-)\d{1,6}', '', s) for s in df['Name'].values]
df['SysNum'] = [int(re.search('(?<=-)\d{1,6}', s)[0]) for s in df['Name'].values]
df['NewName'] = df['BaseName'] + df['SysNum'].astype(str)
```

This takes away the numbers after the - and then I add a new set of numbers back onto the end with the last line.  I now have a set of letters at the end so I need to be able to put in a new set of numbers after the - and keep the letters on at the end.
A new solution to this or a way to use regex that looks at the - and stop at the next set of letters should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].replace('- ', f"-{x['SysNum']} "), axis=1)
# => df['Count']
#    0      car-1 at
#    1      car-2 ar
#    2    truck-3 br
#    3      car-4 at
#    Name: Count, dtype: object
```

This is just replacing `-` + space with `-` + SysNum column value + space.

If you want to make sure you insert the values after the first word that has a `-` after it, you may use a regex:

```py
df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'^\w+-', fr"\g<0>{x['SysNum']}", x["Name"]), axis=1)
# => df
#         Name  SysNum       Count
# 0    car- at       1    car-1 at
# 1    car- ar       2    car-2 ar
# 2  truck- br       3  truck-3 br
# 3    car- at       4    car-4 at
```

Here, `^\w+-` matches start of string (`^`), `\w+` matches one or more letters/digits/`_`, and then `-` is matched. The replacement is the whole match value (`\g<0>`) + the value from the `SysNum` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and list comprehension!.

```
>>> df['NewCol'] = [name.replace("-", f"-{num}", 1) for name, num in zip(df.Name, df.SysNum)]
>>> df
        Name  SysNum      NewCol
0    car- at       1    car-1 at
1    car- ar       2    car-2 ar
2  truck- br       3  truck-3 br
3    car- at       4    car-4 at
```

Note: The third argument to the `replace` method ensure that we replace only the first occurrence of `-`

Answer (score 0):

```py
parts = df['Name'].str.split('-', n=1)
df['NewName'] = parts.str[0] + '-' + df['SysNum'].astype(str) + parts.str[1]
```

Test:

```
>>> df
        Name  SysNum     NewName
0    car- at       1    car-1 at
1    car- ar       2    car-2 ar
2  truck- br       3  truck-3 br
3    car- at       4    car-4 at
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
df["Count"] = [f"{pre}-{num} {suf}" for num, [pre, suf] in zip(df["SysNum"], df["Name"].str.split("- "))]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
        Name  SysNum       Count
0    car- at       1    car-1 at
1    car- ar       2    car-2 ar
2  truck- br       3  truck-3 br
3    car- at       4    car-4 at
```